# Base value of Opacity

Tags: wpf, animation, opacity

Recently, I am confused by following line of code

```
 <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="CommonStatesWrapper"/>
```

According to my understanding, the Opacity would turn to *0* from the base value immediately, because the Duration is *0*. But what's the base value of Opacity?

Comment: Base value of opacity is 1 I think, but you have to explicitly set it when animating the value. So if you were to animate the opacity of a button you have to set button opacity to 1 even though this is the initial value.

Comment: Yes. Sometimes it might inherit the value form another animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [UIElement.Opacity Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.opacity.aspx) page on MSDN:

> Default opacity is 1.0. Expected values are between 0.0 and 1.0.

...

> The 1.0 default value is the default provided by the initial metadata
>   of this dependency property on the UIElement class. Other derived
>   classes may potentially change this default value by overriding the
>   metadata from within their class constructor.)